# C# Discord.Net MessageReceived event Content-property is an empty string

Tags: c#, string, discord, event-handling, .net-6.0

I'm currently in the process of rewriting my Discord Bot because the old one was still running on the .Net 4.8 Framework and I therefore didn't have access to the new features and the code was not well written in many places. That's why I have started rewriting the bot in .Net 6 with the current version of the library (3.8.1).

The problem I'm currently having is that in my command handler, the content property for the MessageReceived event is an empty string. All over the internet there is talk of the Message Content Gateway Intent in the Discord Developer Portal, but I have this intent enabled and when I launch any of my other bots from the application I have the exact same problem.

It can't be a verification either, since the bot is only on 4 servers. Also strange is that everything works as long as the bot is mentioned somewhere in the message, e.g. If I write "ping", then my corresponding command in the module base dont get executed because the SocketMessage content is empty, but when I write "ping @Botname" it works. So it can't be due to read/write permissions in the channel either. In DM chat with the bot I don't have the problem. Slash-commands work fine but I don't want to build the whole bot on slash commands because I have a lot of commands planned and don't want all of them in the command browser. Even downgrading to an older version of the library didn't change anything. Its almost the same code as the one from my old bot, but my old one works without any problems.

[image: Content Empty]

If parts of the code are needed for the problem, please let me know.
Until then, thanks in advance! And I hope it's not so obvious that I got help from the Google Translator.

---

I tried all combinations of gateway intent activations in the developer portal, tested multiple combinations of the GatewayIntents enumerator in the client config, i tried it with other bots and other servers and I even tried it with other discord accounts.

Comment: Could you provide your actual code for the message received event and event handler? Also, it's possible if you are trying to use text commands instead of a message received event without a command identifier it might not always work properly.

Comment: The MessageReceived event wasn't the problem because it reached my breakpoint. I think i got it to work. Two Days Ago, following line caused the bot to crash right after the GuildDownloader was finished:

`GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All`

now it works and the content property isn't empty anymore. I don't know if this was a bug in the Gateway, but i didn't changed anything in the code.

But i still have the problem sometimes, that the slash commands dont work with the error message: "Cannot respond to an interaction after 3 seconds!" but the response time took only 200ms-300ms

Comment: I encountered issues with responding after 3 seconds as quickly as 20ms as well, and after I ran into several similar issues I ended up moving to Dsharp+ instead. Glad you fixed it, that does sound like there's a bug with the gateway wrapper.

Comment: Hi, can you maybe show, how you fixed it? Im getting the same error.